# Nativescript force latest store version

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to figure out how to force the user to use the app only if he has the last update of it( So the app should check if the local and store version are the same). I've seen this feature in some apps. Found this plugin : `https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-store-update`. It works great on iOS but it does not work at all on Android, so I am clueless right now on how to do this. Any help would be much appreaciated. Thanks

Comment: May be make an API call to your backend from the app with app version?

Comment: Can you please ellobrate how you tested on Android, did you use a release build with same keystore as the one uploaded in Google Play?

Comment: I modified in the manifest file the versionCode to a lower one and the version name to a lower one also

Comment: @Manoj Yes, it is the same release build with the same keystore I am using

Answer (score 1):

While not sure about forcing to update the store version, you can use the newly introduced **AppSync** functionality to create mandatory updates for your codebase. See [this blog post](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/enable-live-updates-of-your-ios-and-android-apps-using-nativescript-appsync) for details or just search for **[nativescript-app-sync](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-app-sync)**